# Two rasters created from the same polygon have different extents?

Tags: arcmap, raster, coordinate-system

My problem is that I am trying to export some rasters to Rockworks so that I can create a sand layer from them. Rockworks requires the grid files i use to have the exact same XY co-ordinates.

So i have a polygon of my sand layer - I create one raster of the surface (by using extract by mask from some AHN data I have) and the second one i create myself with a depth of -10.

When i check their layer properties however they are different! e.g. the top extent of the lower raster is `503002.235094748` and the top extent of the upper raster is `503000.235094748`. The left and bottom extents are exactly the same..

They're both in the same co-ordinate system..?!

Comment: I have attempted to recreate the raster with using a cell size of 0.01 but this still gives me an upper extent of 503001.535094748!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any raster-based software it is important to specify both the cellsize *and* the extent of your datasets.  ArcGIS provides several interfaces for this.  (They vary by version and even within version; there are actually multiple non-communicating internal settings!)  Find the settings dialog appropriate for the tool you are using, explicitly specify the output parameters, and redo the exports.